# find the path with least number of jumps for a frog crossing pond using divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

A frog is trying to cross a pond but he can only jumps on stones and he can jump up to five units.

We have been given an array with ones and zeros (zeros for water and ones for stones) and the task to find the best possible approach to find the path with the least number of jump(using divide and conquer if possible).

Example for array -> [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
p.s: the frog starts one unit before the array and have to reach a unit after the array (it is possible that there is no path available with conditions mentioned)

I'm just starting to learn algorithms so it would be nice if you guys help me with the algorithm and code.

Comment: Seems like there's something missing in the problem statement. All the frog needs to do is jump as far as possible. In other words, the solution is a trivial O(n) greedy algorithm.

Comment: @user3386109 I know the greedy algorithm but can u propose a divide and conquer solution

Comment: It really seems like any divide and conquer method will just emulate the greedy method but slower and with more bookkeeping. Is there any reason you want a D&D algorithm for this particular problem?

Comment: @ADdV the problem was offered in the D&D session so I thought it might makes sense to be solved better by a D&D solution

Comment: @ADdV tnx a lot tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea for a divide and conquer approach would be the following:

```
program frog(array)
begin
  divide array after the '1' left of the center of the array;
  foreach (partialArray) do begin
    if (length(partialArray) > 5) then frog(partialArray);
  end foreach;
end.
```

Let's use your given array as an example: `[0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]`

- 1<sup>st</sup> division: `[0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1|0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]`
- 2<sup>nd</sup> division: `[0 0 0 1|0 0 1 0 0 1|0 1 0 0 1|0 1 1 0 0 0 0]`
- 3<sup>rd</sup> division: `[0 0 0 1|0 0 1|0 0 1|0 1 0 0 1|0 1 1|0 0 0 0]`

In this case, the frog would jump to the first, the second, the third, the fifth, and the seventh `1` before reaching the goal (= 6 jumps).

Why does this algorithm work? Let's assume, it wouldn't output a shortest way of jumping for the frog. That would mean, we didn't find the `partialArray`s with the largest jumps for the frog. If one `partialArray` wouldn't resemble a largest jump, that would mean: There would be at least one `1` after the `1` inside the partialArray which the frog can still reach. This isn't possible, since `length(partialArray) ≤ 5` holds. Thus, every `1` after the `partialArray` would be too far away (`> 5`).